# Return parent entities based on (and including) child entities

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to retrieve a list of entities based on properties of their child entities - and include those same child entities. I am using EntityFramework Core 3.1, although I am happy to upgrade to 5.x if there've been any changes that would solve this for me. I have also not explored EntityFramework much beyond some very basic CRUD boilerplate until now, so I am not sure if this is something more LINQ-oriented or specific to EF (Core). The below is a heavily simplified example of a method in a project that I will be using to ultimately return data to a consumer of my API.

A point of interest (`POI`) has a number of historical records (`History`). POI has a `List<History>` and a History has a `PointID` which is used by EF Core to populate the POI's `List<History>`.

Here is how I would get all the POIs and their histories, where a point was first registered since a certain date (using a nullable date parameter for this method)

```cs
var result = _context.POIs
            .Where(point => (registeredSince == null || point.RegisteredAt >= registeredSince))
            .Include(point => point.Histories)
            .ToList();
```

However, my question is.. how would I then get only `POI`s based on an attribute within the `History` of that `POI` (and include those same `History` records?) Or, to use an example; I want to return only `POI`s that have `History` records with an `areaId == 5` (and include those in the results)

One way, without hugely in-depth EF knowledge, would be:

- First run a query to return `History` entities where `history.areaId == 5` and only select `history.PointId`
- Second query would be to get all `POI`s where `id` is in the returned `PointId` list above
- ..including `History` where `history.areaId == 5` (a duplication)

However, I would be running part of this twice, which seems inefficient. Basically, could I efficiently use LINQ/EF to get all `POI`s where `history.areaId == 5` (and then only include those `History` records with an `areaId` of 5)? Would I have to write something that unavoidably loads all `POI` and their `History` records, before I am able to narrow the results down, or is that something EF can happily do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include) introduced in EF Core 5.x, to query like -

```cs
var result = _context.POIs
            .Include(p => p.Histories.Where(h => h.areaId == 5))            
            .ToList();
```

This will return a list of `POI` where each will contain only histories for which `areaId == 5`.

**EDIT:**
If you want only the `POI`s which has any `History` with `areaId == 5`, you can simply filter them accordingly -

```cs
var result = dbCtx.POIs
        .Include(p => p.Histories.Where(h => h.areaId == 5))
        .Where(p => p.Histories.Any(h => h.areaId == 5))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: This nearly works, except I don't want POIs returned if they have no histories (IE I only want to return POIs for the `.Histories.Where(h => h.areaId == 5)`). I could remove all POIs afterwards, where they have no histories, but ideally I wouldn't want them returned to start with..

Comment: This is exactly the answer - and it was the `.Any` that had me stumped yesterday!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following:

```
var result = _context.POIs
    .Include(poi => poi.Histories)
    // Enumerate linked Histories & get the areaId from each into a list)
    // ... then see if that list contains the areaID we're looking for.
    .Where(poi => poi.Histories.Select(h => h.areaId).Contains(areaIdParam))
    .ToList();
```